# Xamarin app connecting with server

Tags: c#, android, web-services, xamarin, server

I've recently started learning Xamarin platform. I know C# at quite good level, and have a little target in case of basic Android development. I want to write an app, which have a list with items, next to each item, there is a counter, you can increase items count or decrease it. That is really simple program as long as you look at app side. The tricky thing is that I want every person, who has the app installed, can manipulate item's number in "global way", so I mean that variable containing that number is the same for each app instance.

I suppose that it must be stored on the server, but I don't know if it's possible to write just using Xamarin with ex. Web Services, or whether I need seperate technology like Node.js.

I appreciate any hints.
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Yes, you need some sort of server side technology to do this.  Which platform you pick to do it is entirely up to you.  Xamarin will work with a wide variety of server platforms.

Comment: Easy tables on Azure is a really simple alternative. If you set up an account with Azure you'll get $250 of free credits to play with it. Check it out https://blog.xamarin.com/getting-started-azure-mobile-apps-easy-tables/

Comment: Well I see that easy tables on Azure can be great way to achive what I want, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what is your goal - regarding technical aspect -, but it seems you need a database on a server. Then your app, the clients, may communicate it through a web service or through sql queries (I don't know yet, if you can use Entity framework), then you update the values for everyone accordingly.
I am also new to Xamarin, do not know its capabilities yet.